# GCC expected template-name before ‘<’ token error

Tags: c++, templates, ubuntu, inheritance, g++

I´ve browsed other similar topics and did not find an answer to my problem...

The code below illustrates the situation. A Base class and a Derived class:

**Base.hpp**

```
namespace test {

template<class T>
class Base {
public:
    Base();
    virtual ~Base();
};

}
```

**Base.cpp**

```
#include "Base.hpp"

namespace test {

template<class T>
Base<T>::Base() {
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub

};

template<class T>
Base<T>::~Base() {
    // TODO Auto-generated destructor stub
};

}
```

**Derived.hpp**

```
namespace test {

class Derived : public Base<int> {
public:
    Derived();
    virtual ~Derived();
};

} /* namespace aeirtuaccess */
```

**Derived.cpp**

```
#include "Derived.hpp"

namespace test {

Derived::Derived() {
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub

};

Derived::~Derived() {
    // TODO Auto-generated destructor stub
};

}
```

When I compile this code with [Coliru - see it in action here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/2ae4fc84346a05f9),  it works fine, but when I go to my Ubuntu environment using g++ I´m having the following error:

```
>g++  Base.cpp Derived.cppIn file included from Derived.cpp:2:0:
Derived.hpp:3:28: error: expected template-name before ‘<’ token
 class Derived : public Base<int> {
                            ^
Derived.hpp:3:28: error: expected ‘{’ before ‘<’ token
Derived.hpp:3:28: error: expected unqualified-id before ‘<’ token
Derived.cpp:6:18: error: invalid use of incomplete type ‘class test::Derived’
 Derived::Derived() {
                  ^
In file included from Derived.cpp:2:0:
Derived.hpp:3:7: error: forward declaration of ‘class test::Derived’
 class Derived : public Base<int> {
       ^
Derived.cpp:11:19: error: invalid use of incomplete type ‘class test::Derived’
 Derived::~Derived() {
                   ^
In file included from Derived.cpp:2:0:
Derived.hpp:3:7: error: forward declaration of ‘class test::Derived’
 class Derived : public Base<int> {
```

Is there any difference between the compilers ? Should I use a specific g++ flag or version ? Is there something else that I need to do to fix that in my Ubuntu environment ?

Comment: What compiler are you using? If you fix the missing `;` at the end of each class and the double `:` it works fine.

Comment: g++.. This is not the code, but the general view of classes structure... I really need help on the class structure the way to inherit from the templated class...

Comment: Please post the *actual* code you are having a problem with. Or at least, please confirm that the code you post here has the same problem that you can reproduce. Otherwise, this is not a legitimate question.

Comment: `This is not the code` It's not the code, but we are supposed to figure out what is real code, what is fake code, and match the compiler error with the real code.  Downvoted.

Comment: You have `::` instead of `:`. You should really just copy and paste exactly what you have.

Comment: Greg, of course this is the same problem I´m facing... Paul, I just don´t feel necessary I need to post real code with a lot of functions and methods if they are not related to the problem...

Comment: @Mendez, *Any* compiler error can be duplicated with a small amount of code.  You just need to take the time to remove the irrelevant code, but still post a complete, compilable, but small code that shows the compiler error.

Comment: @Mendez: The code you have posted *does not cause* the error you describe. So please post code that does.

Comment: Paul, this is a constructive comment... Thanks for sharing... I will do it.

Comment: @Mendez  See here:  http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/a7b806349ad43c36  Note that this small sample taken from your post compiles and runs.  Now take that small sample and add lines to it that will duplicate your error.

Comment: Paul, thanks for the code and for teaching coliru.stacked-crooked.com... I will make use of it...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In `Derived.hpp`, you need to add:

```
#include "Base.hpp"
```

at the top. Otherwise, the compiler doesn't know what `Base` refers to when compiling this file.

Comment: @Mendez: No worries. The reason it works on the Coliru online compiler is you put everything in one source file there, so when the compiler is compiling the `class Derived` definition, it has already seen the `Base` definition. With separate files, you have to tell the compiler where to look.

Comment: Yes, I got this flash when I saw your comment...